# How to use struct to query MongoDB with Golang

Tags: database, mongodb, go

I have an issue with querying mongoDB using golang.

Essentially, I want to return the results of only the documents that are of type []Post.

Here's my code

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"
  "fmt"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

type SecretsStruct struct {
    UserID string `bson:"userid" json:"userid"`
    SecretOne string `bson:"secret_one" json:secret_one`
    SecretTwo string `bson:"secret_two" json:secret_two`
    SecretThree string `bson:"secret_three" json:secret_three`
}
type Post struct {
    //ID        primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
    Title     string             `bson:"title"`
    Body      string             `bson:"body"`
    Tags      []string           `bson:"tags"`
    Comments  uint64             `bson:"comments"`
    CreatedAt time.Time          `bson:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time          `bson:"updated_at"`
}

func main() {
        //Connect to the mongodb
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err = client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)

        //Determine a database & collection to search in
    quickstartDatabase := client.Database("quickstart")
    podcastsCollection := quickstartDatabase.Collection("podcasts")
    //episodesCollection := quickstartDatabase.Collection("episodes")


    cursor, err := podcastsCollection.Find(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var podcasts []Post
    if err = cursor.All(ctx, &podcasts); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(podcasts)
    //fmt.Println(cursor)
}
```

Right now, it outputs all my documents, even though they were not inserted as []Post objects.

Here's the output currently:

```
[{Company Name  [] 0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC} 
{Company Name   [] 0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC} 
{My name is Thomas Hello world [] 0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC} 
{My name is Thomas Hello world [] 0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC} 
{Company Name  [] 0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC}]
```

I would want it to be the following as the My name is Thomas Hello world is not of []Post type:

```
[{Company Name  [] 0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC} 
{Company Name   [] 0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC} 
{Company Name  [] 0 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC}]
```

EDIT:

Here's what the data looks like in mongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f319c9cb384c96b57e13c16"), "title" : "Company Name", "author" : "Thomas" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f319d55ad16c576b7227aa3"), "title" : "Company Name", "author" : "Thomas" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"), "title" : "My name is Thomas", "body" : "Hello world", "tags" : null, "comments" : NumberLong(0), "created_at" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "updated_at" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f348c0df4736ca6b473984d"), "title" : "My name is Thomas", "body" : "Hello world", "tags" : null, "comments" : NumberLong(0), "created_at" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "updated_at" : ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f348dfe125ef44c3c9ad664"), "title" : "Company Name", "author" : "Thomas" }
```

Comment: Define what you mean by "not of Post type". It certainly has some common fields with it. What distinguishes a Post type record from others?

Comment: So Post is my struct that I established in the code. "My name is Thomas" and "Hello world" would be "title" and "author" respectively where as "Company Name" and "[]" would be "title" and "body" respectively. Let me edit the post to show what the documents look like in mongodb.

Comment: The problem is, without a "type" field giving the type of each record the best you can do is to determine the type of a record using $exists clauses. Based on your data, you should be able to pull all Post records with an `author` field to get the posts. Better, add a "type" field to your records (at least, to posts) and search for `type: "post"`